# How exactly Auto scaling works on Google Cloud Run with examples

Tags: google-cloud-run, autoscaling

Google [documents](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) refer 60% as below

> The CPU utilization of existing instances when they are processing
> requests or events, targeting to keep scheduled instances to a 60% CPU
> utilization.

I am confused , suppose I have 0 as minimum instance and 10 as maximum.

1. When the first request is made to the cloud run url, it will start ( if it can in 10 seconds) or else will give HTTP code 429 . This part I guess is OK.
2. Suppose with one request CPU utilization is 40% and then second request comes (  supposing first one is finished and then firs instance will serve that second request, and if the CPU utilization goes to 80%
3. 

(A)  Even If no request, comes , will the cloud Run start a new Instance in anticipation of a new request ?

(B) if a new request comes, will it be handled by the First instance, or that request will wait till the second instance start ( if within 10 second) and then second request will handle that request ?

Answer (score 2):

> (A) Even If no request, comes , will the cloud Run start a new Instance in anticipation of a new request ?

As per my knowledge, it will not start new instances until there are no request, if any requests arrives, 1st it will check if there are any idle instances to handle the request. If requests are not available, then only it will start new instances.

And also as mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere in below comments, Can not predict real scaling model as it may change without any notice and In order to better handle (possible) traffic, the autoscaler can sense a spike in traffic and overprovision instances in advance

> (B) if a new request comes, will it be handled by the First instance, or that request will wait till the second instance start ( if within 10 second) and then second request will handle that request ?

As First instance exceeds the CPU limit, it will either look for another idle instance or start new instance to handle request.

***Note:**  Autoscaling considered based on the type of CPU allocation you choose.*

It is mentioned the [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#choosing-scaling)

> Cloud Run will only scale out when CPU utilization during request processing exceeds 60%.
>
> If you select **CPU always allocated** and perform background activities without requests, Cloud Run will not scale out even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold and in some cases, a container instance might become too busy to accept incoming requests.

Comment: In fact, the real scaling model is not known and change without notice (optimization by the engineering team). By discussing with them, I can say that (A) is not the exact answer. In fact, according with the traffic profile, the autoscaler can "feel" a spike of traffic and overprovision instances in advance to better absorb the (potential) traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I have updated my updated my answer. I have given solution based on my knowledge. please feel free to give suggestions if you have any

Comment: @roopa-m for part B, **As First instance exceeds the CPU limit, it will either look for another idle instance or start new instance to handle request.**

but if the previous instance is already available ( though at >60% CPU), it could be better if the request is handled by the same instance and also at the same time a new instance is started for next requests. Thanks though for answer

Comment: @puzzled, As the other user mentioned, the scaling mechanism is complex and takes several factors into the decision making process, for e.g. CPU, [concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency). And as it is a serverless product, the end user has limited control over the underlying infrastructure. Therefore its not possible to control which instance should serve the request.